# Object.keys for a non-instantiated object interface type

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to use Object.keys on an interface type itself to get all of the properties of that object type?

```
export interface Apple{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  status: string;
}

Object.keys(Apple)
```

Exepected output would be ["id", "name", "status"] like the normal Object.keys. I can't seem to find a way or documentation to accomplish this.

Comment: As Sam Herrmann mentioned, it sounds impossible. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I wanted to set a constant at the top of my file that has all the properties of the interface. I iterate through them for the diffing tool I am writing, so I wanted to keep them dynamic in case any properties got added or deleted.

Comment: Isn't that the reason why we use Typescript? `class Foo implements Bar` would complain if `Foo` is missing some implementations in `Bar`. If you want to prevent modification in runtime, you could try `Object.freeze`. Though I have a feeling that's not exactly something you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because TypeScript is only present at development time. Once your code is transpiled to JavaScript, there is no way to reference back to TypeScript types at runtime.

Comment: That's a bummer. But makes sense. I guess I will have to hardcode the property names and just update it manually if there are any changes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From documentation I see the following for return value of `Object.keys()`:

> An array of strings that represent all the enumerable properties of the given object.

Source: [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Which means for example if you have a class what you instantiate from JavaScript then you can get the keys into an array but not from the interface (from TypeScript):

```js
let redApple = new Apple();
let keys = Object.keys(redApple);
let classKeys = Object.keys(Apple);

console.log('keys of the instance', keys);
console.log('keys of the class', classKeys); 

function Apple() {
  this.id = '';
  this.name = '';
  this.status = '';
}
```

We should remember always that at the end TypeScript will be transpiled to JavaScript.